# Child losing its weak reference to parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have an AMContact object where one of its strong properties is an array of AMEmailAddress objects. One contact can have many email addresses. Can I create a strong property on my email address object that points to the contact object?

I feel like if its a strong reference there could be a retain cycle. If I make it weak, when I do my query to get all of the email address objects, at some point the contact object for each one is becoming nil.

```
- (NSArray*)allEmailAddresses
{
    NSArray *allContacts = [self allContacts];
    NSMutableArray *emailAddresses = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (AMContact *contact in allContacts) {
        if (contact.emailAddresses) {
            for (AMEmailAddress *address in contact.emailAddresses) {
                [emailAddresses addObject:address];
            }
        }
    }
    if (emailAddresses.count > 0) {
        return emailAddresses;
    }
    return nil;
} 


@interface AMContact : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;


// arrays of AMEmailAddress, AMPhoneNumber objects
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *emailAddresses;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *phoneNumbers;

@end

@interface AMEmailAddress : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *label;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AMContact *contact; // IS THIS OK OR A RETAIN CYCLE?

@end
```

Comment: You said that "at some point the contact object for each one is becoming nil" - when exactly does this happen? In part of the code that you posted or in a different method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short and simple answer to your question: Can I create a strong property on my email address object that points to the contact object?

Can you? Yes. Should you? Absolutely not.  Your model design already hints at what the relationship should be - the AMContact objects owns the email addresses, not the other way around. Having email addresses have a strong reference to the parent object is not a good way to go about this. The reference from child back to owner should be weak. The fact that your AMContact instance is going to nil is an issue with scoping and design and you shouldn't use a strong reference to get around this.

As for why your AMContact instance is going nil - It's a bit odd because if the AMContact object goes to nil, its child objects should as well. Is it going nil in the code you posted, or at some other point in some other method? Seeing the code where you're trying to refer to it, and it's nil, would be good.

UPDATE:

If you want a list of contacts that have email addresses, you should change the method to return that. However I'm guessing what you mean is that you want a list of their email addresses with their associated contacts. In this case you would have to flip the relationship around and consider the email to be the parent, and the contact to be the child. Note that if a contact has multiple email addresses then you'll have multiple references to the same contact. Assuming you have a `contact` property of type `AMContact` in your `AMEmailAddress` object, I would add a line as follows:

```
for (AMEmailAddress *address in contact.emailAddresses) {

            //Assign the contact as a property of the email address
            //Make sure the contact property is strong
            address.contact = contact;

            [emailAddresses addObject:address];
        }

 //Nil out the emailAddresses array
 contact.emailAddresses = nil;
```

UPDATE:

Ok so now you should have a flipped object - `emailAddress` as the parent and `contact` as the child, with no strong reference from `contact` to `emailAddress` anymore. This means you won't be able to re-use the `contact` object to get email addresses again though. If you need to maintain the original `contact` object as-is then you're right, you'll have to store it as a property in the View Controller or in another class - for approaches like this where I have to deal with people objects (for allowing users to invite friends, etc) I use a 'People Manager' singleton and keep all the original objects there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think what's happening in the allEmailAddresses method is I'm getting an array of all contacts, finding the ones with email, and then saving and returning just the email objects. No one is retaining this original array of contacts, which must be why its going to nil. How do i prevent this?

Comment: Updated answer - let me know if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks. It will work in this case, but other times I need the contacts to be the objects i vend. So in that case it doesn't seem to work that my email address array is a weak property. A solution I've tried is to vend out the array of contacts to the view controller, keep a reference to that in a property, and then grab my email objects using the same routine as above. That works because someone is maintaining a strong reference to the contacts objects. The downside is that they are occupying some memory I didn't want to use. Is this an ok design?

Comment: When you say "I need the contacts to be the objects i vend" - you mean that the contacts should be the ones returned from your `allContacts` method? If so, then they're the same objects since we're just passing references. However you would have to flip the relationship - that is, nil out the `emailAddresses` array of the `AMContact` object once you're done with it. I'll update the code above.

Comment: Ok I have a working design now. Thank you for all of your help. The people manager type approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your case, I think it's very clear that Contact is the owner (parent) of his email addresses, so you will avoid any cycles by just designing this relation in that way, i.e. using weak reference back to contact. If you use a strong ref, then you will have a retain cycle because NSArray retains it's children in `emailAdresses`.

Now, I would check your program structure to see how and why you lose contacts in that weak reference, something must be releasing them, perhaps, your contact leaves scope prematurely?

You can get more info and advice in this [great article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html) on retain cycles, there are some workarounds as well, but I would encourage you to stick to a design that makes more sense.